# Framework for a PHP admin page and forms, with existing database

Tags: php, framework, bootstrap

I need to create a PHP admin page and I really like [something like this](http://eliteadmin.themedesigner.in/demos/eliteadmin-inverse-php/index.php):

If you click the link you'll see a menu on the left and the page on the right. It's responsive and works in all browsers and smartphones. That's what I need and for now I don't need many features. I need a PHP framework that's able to work with an already existing MySQL database to retrieve data from the MySQL and update it using forms. It'll be pretty basic at the beginning but would like to start off with a good base so I can add additional features in the future.

So page1 would be view/edit own details. page2 will be to show their invoices. page3 wil be an invoice page. page4 will be a list of documents where they can click a link to download it and page5 will be a contact page (a form that submits to php) ... Very very basic if you read it like that but it has to be responsive, nice looking, compatible with a php framework that's not too difficult to learn... and more features will be added late so it would be nice if the framework has graphs etc.. not required I guess there are many options but maybe someone can recommend me something good?

Looking on themeforest there seem to be a lot of bootstrap admin templates available but I'm not sure which PHP framework they are supposed to be working with.

---

I'm not new to programming but I didn't program anything in PHP in recent years so I prefer a PHP framework without a steep learning curve.

Can anyone recommend me some good combination of PHP framework and bootstrap based admin page so I build something easily?

I thought that maybe CakePHP is an easy one. I just read the "blog" example code and it seems pretty easy to use. But I'm not sure if there's such a bootstrap theme available that works easily with CakePHP.
And is CakePHP still a wise choice? There are so many frameworks these days....

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: OK, thanks – integrated that with your question, and will cleanup comments then. I don't know anything to recommend you – but with the details collected now, others will have a better idea. Good luck!

Comment: I think that you will find that most such free dashboards are client-side these days. That way, AJAX can be used for partial screen updates, whereas PHP would have to re-render the entire page for each small change. I was in your shoes, decades of PHP, and eventually taught myself AngularJs (1.x), and now all my GUI stuff is client side & my PHP only handles AJAX requests and the database. Perhaps you might consider that?